# What are the metrics to evaluate a machine learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to know what are the `various techniques` and `metrics` used to evaluate how accurate/good an algorithm is and how to use a given metric to derive a conclusion about a ML model.

one way to do this is to use precision and recall, as defined [here in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall). 
Another way is to use the accuracy metric as explained [here](http://fr.slideshare.net/nicbet/computing-accuracy-precision-and-recall-presentation). So, what I would like to know is whether there are other metrics for evaluating an ML model?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've compiled, a while ago, a list of metrics used to evaluate classification and regression algorithms, under the form of a [cheatsheet](http://www.damienfrancois.be/blog/files/modelperfcheatsheet.pdf). Some metrics for classification: precision, recall, sensitivity, specificity, F-measure, Matthews correlation, etc. They are all based on the confusion matrix. Others exist for regression (continuous output variable).

The technique is mostly to run an algorithm on some data to get a model, and then apply that model on new, previously unseen data, and evaluate the metric on that data set, and repeat.

Some techniques (actually [resampling techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29) from statistics):

- Jacknife
- Crossvalidation
- K-fold validation
- bootstrap.

Comment: How is crossvalidation different from k-fold validation?

Comment: @lejlot Definitions vary, but originally, cross validation was 2-fold validation (k-fold with k=2) repeated several times with random partitioning of the data

Answer (score 0):

Talking about ML in general is a quite vast field, but I'll try to answer any way. The Wikipedia definition of ML is the following

> Machine learning, a branch of artificial intelligence, concerns the construction and study of systems that can learn from data.

In this context learning can be defined parameterization of an algorithm. The parameters of the algorithm are derived using input data with a known output. When the algorithm has "learned" the association between input and output, it can be tested with further input data for which the output is well known.

Let's suppose your problem is to obtain words from speech. Here the input is some kind of audio file containing one word (not necessarily, but I supposed this case to keep it quite simple). You'd record X words N times and then use (for example) N/2 of the repetitions to parameterize your algorithm, disregarding - at the moment - how your algorithm would look like.

Now on the one hand - depending on the algorithm - if you feed your algorithm with one of the remaining repetitions, it may give you some certainty estimate which may be used to characterize the recognition of just one of the repetitions. On the other hand you may use all of the remaining repetitions to test the learned algorithm. For each of the repetitions you pass it to the algorithm and compare the expected output with the actual output. After all you'll have an accuracy value for the learned algorithm calculated as the quotient of correct and total classifications.

Anyway, the actual accuracy will depend on the quality of your learning and test data.

A good start to read on would be *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* by *Christopher M Bishop*

Comment: As mentioned before, there is not only the accuracy, but also the certainty, which is, even if a pattern is classified to belong to a class, the input vector may differ from the most likely input vector for that class. This could be considered as the likelyhood of an input vector to belong to the class in some algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

There are various metrics for evaluating the performance of ML model and there is no rule that there are 20 or 30 metrics only. You can create your own metrics depending on your problem. There are various cases wherein when you are solving real - world problem where you would need to create your own custom metrics.
Coming to the existing ones, it is already listed in the first answer, I would just highlight each metrics merits and demerits to better have an understanding.

1. Accuracy is the simplest of the metric and it is commonly used. It is the number of points to class 1/ total number of points in your dataset. This is for 2 class problem where some points belong to class 1 and some to belong to class 2. It is not preferred when the dataset is imbalanced because it is biased to balanced one and it is not that much interpretable.
2. Log loss is a metric that helps to achieve probability scores that gives you better understanding why a specific point is belonging to class 1. The best part of this metric is that it is inbuild in logistic regression which is famous ML technique.
3. Confusion metric is best used for 2-class classification problem which gives four numbers and the diagonal numbers helps to get an idea of how good is your model.Through this metric there are others such as precision, recall and f1-score which are interpretable.